# Google Charts: ChartWrapper and Formatters (NumberFormat)

Tags: charts, google-visualization

How do I use ChartWrapper and a formatter to add a suffix to the tooltip on line / bar charts?
This is my code for the ChartWrapper

```
function drawChartb() {

    var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    dataTable: [['Person', 'Score'], [1, .50], [2, .25]],
    options: {'legend': 'bottom', 'colors': ['#D70005'], 'chartArea': {left: 40, top: 10, width: 450}, 'vAxis': {format: '#,###%', 'viewWindow': {max: 1.05, min: .2}}, 'pointSize': 6},
    containerId: 'chart_div'
    });

    wrapper.draw();
}
```

This is how I did it without using a chartwrapper.

```
// set tooltip as percentage
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
pattern: '#%', 
fractionDigits: 2
});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your data outside the wrapper, use the [formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) on it, and then set the dataTable to be equal to that data source:

```
function drawVisualization() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Person', 'Score'], [1, .50], [2, .25]
    ]);

  // set tooltip as percentage
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#%',
    fractionDigits: 2
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {'legend': 'bottom', 'colors': ['#D70005'], 'chartArea': {left: 40, top: 10, width: 450}, 'vAxis': {format: '#,###%', 'viewWindow': {max: 1.05, min: .2}}, 'pointSize': 6},
    containerId: 'visualization'
  });


  wrapper.draw();
}
```

Result:

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Great idea using the combination of arrayToDataTable and ChartWrapper. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those who generate their chart data using [Google JSON schema](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) and cannot get NumberFormat to work with ChartWrapper, you can apply formatting directly to the row *"f":null*

### To note:

- I have found the [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) constructor method works with [DataTables](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#datatable-class) but not with [ChartWrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapper-class).

**Using DataTable > OK**

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data); 
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '$'});
formatter.format(dataTable, 1);
```

**Using ChartWrapper  > BAD**

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '$'});
formatter.format(data, 1);

var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    dataTable: data,
    options: myPieChartOptions(),
    containerId: 'chart_div'
});
```

### This is how I properly formatted my data using Google JSON.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "cols": [
          {"id":"","label":"Product","pattern":"","type":"string"},
          {"id":"","label":"Sales","pattern":"","type":"number"}
        ],
    "rows": [
          {"c":[{"v":"Nuts","f":null},{"v":945.59080870918,"f":"$945.59"}]}
        ]
 }
```

And here's the PHP code to generate that JSON

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 0);

// init  arrays
$result['cols'] = array();
$result['rows'] = array();

// add col data
$result['cols'][] = array(
    "id" => "",
    "label" => "Product",
    "pattern" => "",
    "type" => "string"
);
$result['cols'][] = array(
    "id" => "",
    "label" => "Sales",
    "pattern" => "",
    "type" => "number"
);

$nutsTotalFormat =  "$".number_format($nutsTotal, 2);

$result['rows'][]["c"] = array(array("v" => "Nuts","f" => null),array("v" => $nutsTotal,"f" => $nutsTotalFormat ));
```

Pie chart will show the formatted result of $nutsTotalFormat

"$945.59"